# how to pass variable to Cache::remember function

Tags: laravel

Laravel docs give this example:

```
$value = Cache::remember('users', $minutes, function() {
    return DB::table('users')->get();
});
```

In my case I have

```
public function thumb($hash, $extension)
{
    Cache::remember('thumb-'.$hash, 15, function() {
        $image = Image::where('hash', $hash)->first();
    });
```

If I run that I get `ErrorException in ImageController.php line 69: Undefined variable: hash`. I tried to pass $hash to function like so:

```
Cache::remember('thumb-'.$hash, 15, function($hash)
```

but then got another error as below:

> Missing argument 1 for App\Http\Controllers\ImageController::App\Http\Controllers{closure}(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\imagesharing\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Cache\Repository.php on line 316 and defined

How do I pass argument so I can use it in my query?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to pass it using `use`.

```
Cache::remember('thumb-'.$hash, 15, function() use ($hash) {
    $image = Image::where('hash', $hash)->first();
});
```

Comment: To add a little more detail - this is not a laravel issue, this is how closures/anonymous functions work in PHP.  See.[PHP Docs] (http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

Comment: I decided to use forever instead of remeber, and this Cache::forever('thumb-'.$hash, function() use($hash) gives me Exception in FileStore.php line 102: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed, is it not possible to use closure with forever?

Comment: No, `remember` will retrieve from the cache if the key already exist, otherwise will insert what the closure is returning.  With `forever` all you are doing is adding an item to the cache, there's no need for a closure there.

Comment: php 8 you can do: cache()->remember(key, value, fn() => dd($hash));